# How to clear cache of NSURLSession when a large file is downloading?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, download, clear-cache

I am using NSURLSession to download a large video file in background. In this iOS application I implemented pause, resume and stop downloading feature.

Here is my code :

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
```

in .m

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration;
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(ver >= 8)
{
    sessionConfiguration =  [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"sessionID"];
}
else
{
    sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"sessionID"];
}

sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 delegateQueue:nil];
```

For stop downloading I am using this method:

```
- (void)stopDownloading:(id)sender {        
    // Cancel the task.
    [self.fdi.downloadTask cancel];        
}
```

It works quite well with a large amount of files, but there is an inconvenience. When I stop downloading then Memory which is used in downloading is not released so the application size is continuously for stopped downloading tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[self.session invalidateAndCancel];
```

as Per documentation

> It will cancels all outstanding tasks and then invalidates the session.

Also, You can fetch the cache directory and then by using a loop or something fetch and remove folder and data inside.